# get _complete_ process name from pid

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I am in a kernel module and I want to have the whole process name
from a given pid. exactly: I want the line which is hold in /proc/PID/cmdline.

The problem is that `task_struct->comm[]` is only 15 bytes long and doesn't handle
if a program changes his `argv[]` manually or via setproctitle(3)...

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always look at how the kernel does it. You'll see the function:

```
proc_pid_cmdline(struct task_struct *task, char * buffer)
```

It's fairly easy to follow but once you have the `task_struct` for the process you are interested in you use `access_process_vm()` to slurp the bits you want from `mm->arg_start`.

Comment: I was using this function BUT with this I cannot access the whole argv, only argv[0] :(

Comment: thomasbl: You are accessing the whole argv, you're just stopping at the first `'\0'`, which is the end of `argv[0]` - each element is separated by a `'\0'`.

Comment: thank you for the right answer of my problem!
But I don't read your answer yesterday and so today I found it out by myself :)

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with opening the `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` file and just reading the contents?

Comment: the problem is that I am hijacked the open() syscall and if I try to open the /proc/pid/cmdline for reading I'll end up in an endless loop.

Comment: Wouldn't you have simply chained the syscall? In other words, save its last value before you (so eloquently) hijacked it. In that case you would be able to just call the old one.

Comment: Otherwise you would have to provide all the open functionality in your intercept, rather than just having to add your code to do new stuff and letting the old stuff be handled by the kernel proper.